# Is it possible to mock/fake a variable in a python function during unit_test

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

Example class function to be tested.

```
from hal import async_event
import timer

global async_event
class myclass:
   def __init__():
      pass

   def wait_on_event():
      delay = 30
      alarm = timer.set_timer(delay)
      while not async_event:
         do_something()
         if alarm.is_timedout:
            break
      print("async_event={}".format(async_event))
      return alarm.is_timedout
```

The unit test code

```
import unittest
import myclass
class my_tester(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_wait_on_event(self):
      test_event = myclass
      self.assertEquals(True, test_event.wait_on_event())
```

I want to test that wait_on_event() will time out, but I don't want to wait 30 seconds. I don't want to patch set_timer() as this is important to the test. I would like to "mock?" the variable "delay" with a small value like 1.
Is there some way to override a variable? What if delay was a class attribute?
Is there a better way to handle timeout cases so they can be sped up during unit test?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a default parameter in your `wait_on_event()` method and remove setting delay in the method itself:

e.g.

```
def wait_on_event(delay=30):
      alarm = timer.set_timer(delay)
      while not async_event:
```

What this does, is by default 30 seconds is your delay. Unless you overwrite it when calling the `wait_on_event()` with another value.

So in your unit test, pass in what ever value you want to wait:

```
self.assertEquals(True, test_event.wait_on_event(1))
```

Comment: Oh my gosh that was so obvious. Thanks. I was so stuck on using some form of mock. But I still don't know if there is a way to mock a value.

Comment: The default parameter solution works because I have access to the function call source code. If this was not the case, can a function variable value be substituted during unit test?

Comment: I am not really keen with `unittest`. I would imagine unless the piece `self.assertEquals` has a way to force the shorter timeout, your going to have to wait the 30 seconds.